# How to Improve Performance of Lambda Function which Connects to Amazon MQ

Tags: java, aws-lambda, activemq-classic, spring-jms, amazon-mq

Context: I have an AWS lambda function which is trying to publish messages to Amazon MQ after all the functionality of function is completed. The lambda function is build on Spring Boot. For the JMS connectivity I have used the Spring JmsTemplate.

Problem: Since the bean required for connectivity are already handled by Spring's JmsTemplate at initialization I expected the time taken to publish message to the queue would be less but I observe the time taken to publish a message is over 200ms.

Question 1: How can I reduce the time taken to publish message to MQ?
Question 2: Should I remove JMS template and manually manage the connection to MQ?

Since spring JMS template is a singleton bean I expected to see the lambda function use less time publishing the messages during subsequent invocation but it was not the case. The publishing time remained same across all the lambda function invocation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are the 200ms end to end, from executing your lambda function (manually?) to the message being published? Because then you could look into preventing cold starts, making your function and dependencies smaller so Lambda can spin it up faster et cetera.

Comment: @AltayAkkus no. The lambda function is already initialized. The 200 ms is the time difference when I invoke the method which has the logic to publish the message to mq.

Answer (score 2):

This is a well-known issue with Spring's JmsTemplate. It's documented in both [ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas) and in [Spring's JmsTemplate JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html) which states:

> **NOTE: The ConnectionFactory used with this template should return pooled Connections (or a single shared Connection) as well as pooled Sessions and MessageProducers. Otherwise, performance of ad-hoc JMS operations is going to suffer.**

Please ensure you're using a connection pool with Spring JmsTemplate otherwise it's going to create a new connection, session, & producer *every* time it sends a message which is a massive waste of resources.